# ArrayList gets manipulated by called method

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm currently having problems with the following, using Java 8:

I want to pass an `ArrayList<String>` as argument to another method. This method, among other things, removes an object from the ArrayList it was given:

```
public static void calledMethod(String item, ArrayList<String> list) {
    list.remove(item);
}
```

Now I tried calling this method like this from main:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String item = itr.next();  //<-
    calledMethod(item, list);
}
```

In this case, the JVM returns a **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException** at the marked line in the code above (`//<-`). As far as my knowledge goes, this means that the list was modified while it was iterated. But how can this happen? As far as I know, Java hands method arguments by value, not by reference. If I call `calledMethod` using the following code in my main method, no error occurs:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String item = itr.next();  //<-
    calledMethod(item, (ArrayList<String>) list.clone());
}
```

So passing a cloned object to `calledMethod` works. What is wrong here?

---

`java -version`: Java SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)

I'm using Oracle Java on a Linux Mint 64bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Java is pass by value.  But what is `list`?  It's a reference to the actual `ArrayList` object.  When it's passed to the method, it's copied, but the copy still refers to the same object, so the method's modification is visible to the calling method, and a `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs.

When you clone the object, only then is a copy of the object made, preventing the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: What do you mean by "[`list` is] a reference to the actual `ArrayList` object"? How is this possible, if Java, as you just wrote, is pass-by-value?

Comment: The reference itself is passed by value.  That's why both `list`s in the different methods refer to the same `ArrayList`.  It is as if the object was passed by reference, but it's the reference that is passed by value.

Comment: @the_Seppi: "reference" means "pointer to an object". `List`, `ArrayList`, etc. are *reference types*. All non-primitive types in Java are reference types. So `list` is a pointer. Copying a pointer produces another pointer that points to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that your iterator got "lost" due to "concurrent" modification on the list (it's not actually concurrent, but it's a modification made on the list without notifying the iterator. So from Iterator point of view, it's as if the list was modified at the same time)

While iterating through a list, you should never remove an element with List.remove. Use Iterator.remove instead, this way the iterator won't have an invalid state due to removing:

```
Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String item = itr.next();
    itr.remove(); // will remove "item" and keep iterator in a correct state
}
```

Comment: While this will prevent a `ConcurrentModificationException`, the OP is asking about why the exception still occurs when the list is passed to the method for the remove operation; not why removing from the list while iterating it causes the exception.

Comment: "As far as my knowledge goes, this means that the list was modified while it was iterated. But how can this happen?" => I'm trying to answer that

Answer (score 0):

Yes you pass it by value, but you are passing an object which is actually passing the reference of the object in that case. Thus you are still modifying the actualy list in the calledMethod.